# Compiling C# scripts is slow

Tags: c#, .net, scripting, codedom

I have an application that uses "scripts" written in C#, compiled on start-up using the C# CodeDomProvider. Loading a few dozen, even >170 scripts isn't much of a problem, I compile them and then save the assemblies into a cache folder for the next startup. For 170 scripts this initial compilation takes about 1.5 minutes.

However, when I tried to load >1000 scripts it took well over an hour to compile them all. I added a Stopwatch and learned that every script takes a little bit longer to load than the one before, in the case of 170 files it went from ~150ms for the first one to >650ms for the last one, increasing bit by bit for every file.

I know I could reduce my load time drastically in general by combining the scripts to one big file, but for several reasons I'd prefer it a lot if I could compile them separately :/ It makes reloading them easy and fast, I don't have to worry about recompiling the whole scripts folder when something changes, I can easily give a progress bar for the compilation progress, etc.

Now my question is, what's the problem here? Why does the compile time per file increase over time? And can I do something about that?

**Edit**

I'll *try* to give more information, as request in the comments.

As I've said, I'm compiling every script using the C# CodeDomProvider, basically the following in a loop, for every of my currently 171 script files, with each file containing one or multiple classes that I instantiate after the assembly was created:

```
var provider = System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp"); ;
var parameters = new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters();
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => !a.IsDynamic).Select(a => a.Location).ToArray());
parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
parameters.GenerateInMemory = false;
parameters.OutputAssembly = tmpFileName + ".compiled";
parameters.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
parameters.WarningLevel = 0;
var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(parameters, tmpFileName);
asm = results.CompiledAssembly;
```

I get the same results using CS-Script, which does something similar.

```
asm = CSScript.LoadWithConfig(tmpFileName, null, debug, CSScript.GlobalSettings, "/warnaserror- /warn:0");
```

The created assembly is then saved into a cache folder. That saved assembly is used when the script file is older than the assembly, so I don't have to compile it again.

That it gets slower and slower over time becomes obvious when you sit in front of it, watching the progress bar advance slower and slower, so I added a simple Stopwatch call around the above code, `StartNew, Stop, Elapsed`, nothing fancy. The result reflects what I saw on the progress bar, with each additional file the compile time increased.

```
timer.Restart();

// compile as shown above

timer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(asm.Location + ": " + timer.Elapsed);
```

A slight difference between files is to be expected of course, depending on how big they are, and how complex, but the scripts are generally all more or less the same in size and complexity, and I'm witnessing a consistent increase over time.

```
Temp\tmpDDD7.tmp.compiled: 00:00:00.1389177
Temp\tmpDE74.tmp.compiled: 00:00:00.1327150
...
Temp\tmpE156.tmp.compiled: 00:00:00.1719746
Temp\tmpE213.tmp.compiled: 00:00:00.1431011
...
Temp\tmpF05C.tmp.compiled: 00:00:00.1696297
Temp\tmpF118.tmp.compiled: 00:00:00.1739564
...
Temp\tmpF7D5.tmp.compiled: 00:00:00.1824292
Temp\tmpF891.tmp.compiled: 00:00:00.1819889
...
Temp\tmp29F1.tmp.compiled: 00:00:00.2912163
Temp\tmp2B2B.tmp.compiled: 00:00:00.2909096
...
Temp\tmp362F.tmp.compiled: 00:00:00.3161408
Temp\tmp3773.tmp.compiled: 00:00:00.3170768
...
Temp\tmpA4C9.tmp.compiled: 00:00:00.5457990
Temp\tmpA6FC.tmp.compiled: 00:00:00.5460514
```

Comment: You've given us a vague description of your issue without giving us the means to reproduce it. You've also not shown us any benchmarks and your benchmark methodology that points to what the speeds are at each step in the chain. This has the potential to be a great question, but we need a lot more than what you've given us.

Comment: Do you compile scripts individually? If you manage to combine scripts into same file and then compile you will have less overhead added. *Why does the compile time per file increase over time* - you really have to provide more details to get an answer.

Comment: Added more information as requested.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I didn't think more information was required, as I expected this to be an more or less obvious problem, that I was just unable to find more info about for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason compilation becomes slower and slower is because every created assembly is added as a reference to all following script files. On the first file it might be 10 references, on the second it's 11, on the third it's 12, and so on. The more references, the longer the compilation takes. That's what the following line does, and what CS-Script does by default as well.

```
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => !a.IsDynamic).Select(a => a.Location).ToArray());
```

Unfortunately I *want* the scripts to be able to reference each other, so I'll now have to come up with a reference system. But at least I know what the problem is. Maybe I'll try to automate it, remembering what types can be found in which assembly, to automatically reference them down the line.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it can be the cause of that behavior. In fact most likely it is.

You can easily change the behavior by setting CSScript.ShareHostRefAssemblies to true.

Though in this case you will need to take care about the all scripts referencing other scripts. One way of doing this can be by supplying the desired assembly file name (in `Load(string scriptFile, string assemblyFile...)` for all 'shareable' scripts and then using these file names as a input for the all scripts you load.

```
//Assembly Load(string scriptFile, string assemblyFile, bool debugBuild, params string[] refAssemblies)
CSScript.Load("common_scriptA.cs", "asmA.dll", false);
CSScript.Load("common_scriptB.cs", "asmB.dll", false);
CSScript.Load("common_scriptC.cs", "asmC.dll", false);
CSScript.Load("normal_scriptA.cs", null, false, "asmC.dll", "asmB.dll", "asmC.dll");
CSScript.Load("normal_scriptB.cs", null, false, "asmC.dll", "asmB.dll", "asmC.dll");
```